# What does it mean by constraint specification not allowed here?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
   (FName Varchar2(20) CONSTRAINT MyTable_FName_def DEFAULT 'MyName',
   LName varchar2(20) );
```

I got the following error when I run the above query,

```
constraint specification not allowed here
```

Comment: **WHAT** RDBMS??? SQL = Structured Query Language - that's **not** a database product....

Comment: I suspect that specifying a constraint there is not allowed.

Comment: A default value is not a constraint!

Answer (score 1):

If you examine [The Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE), you'll see that a `DEFAULT` value does not need a `CONSTRAINT` keyword

You should use:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    (
        FName Varchar2(20) DEFAULT 'MyName',
        LName Varchar2(20)
    );
```

Comment: `varchar2` is Oracle but your assumption is correct nevertheless. Btw: please do **not** link to completely outdated versions of Postgres (8.1). And besides there is no such language as "psql" (neither in Oracle, nor in Postgres).